Why are certain famous maxims omitted from Avot?
Mesechet Avot contains saying from many famous Tana'im. However there are certain Tana'im whose most famous saying are omitted. For example, Hillel is cited several times in Avot but his maxim of "what is hateful to you do not do to your friend" (Shabbat 31a) is not found in Avot. Similarly, Rebbi Akiva's statement that "loving your neighbor as yourself is a great principle of the Torah" (Yerushalmi Nedarim 9:3[4]) is absent as well.
I would like to know if any commentators note and explain the reason why certain well-known sayings are not included in Avot.

Just because those quotes became famous doesn't mean they were regular sayings.

Maybe Avot wanted to avoid repetition of maxims found elsewhere in Shas?

I think your question reflects a certain misunderstanding of the nature of Jewish sources (from the Tanakh to the Talmud). All those are compilations, not works of a single author/s. This is why we see repetitions, contradictions, different versions of the same statement/story, etc. That's why for the rest of the Mishna we have the Baraytah, and for Avoth we have Kalla Rabati https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tractate_Kallah_Rabbati.2?lang=he

You can see that many Laws of Shabbos are omitted from the Mishnah in Shabbos. And that's true for all others. So you definitely point to a rule rather than an exception.
